# SyntaxError with multi-inheritance and metaclass definition

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, metaclass

I'm running into a really strange error. My project involves the following code segment:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session


class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

    def get_instance(cls):
        return cls._instances[cls]


class SessionManager(object, metaclass=Singleton):

    _engines = {}
    _db_config = {}

    def __init__(self, db_config: dict, **kwargs):
        """
        Parent initializer.  Takes SQLAlchemy database config parameters.
        :param db_config: Database config, consisting of known SQLAlchemy
        config key/values
        :type db_config: dict
        :return: self
        """
        self._engine = None
        self._engine_string = None
        self._db_config = db_config
   
      ...
      ...
```

When I run with Python 3.5 in macOS, it is working. However, when I migrate the project to Ubuntu 18.04 and run with Python 3.6, it complains for syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 5, in <module>
    from views import default
  File "/home/john/p/a/views/default.py", line 11, in <module>
    from utils.TaskManagerQueue import TaskManagerQueue
  File "/home/john/p/a/utils/TaskManagerQueue.py", line 5, in <module>
    from utils.SessionManager import SessionManager
  File "/home/john/p/a/utils/SessionManager.py", line 19
    class SessionManager(object, metaclass=Singleton):
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have searched online and confirmed that the class multi-inheritance `class SessionManager(object, metaclass=Singleton)` is correct. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're actually using Python *2* on your Ubuntu machine. Under Python 2, metaclasses were set using [a `__metaclass__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation). [Keyword-style metaclasses](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/) were [added in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax).

Depending how you've installed Python, you may need to call your code using `python3` or even `python3.6`, not `python`. Note that the [default `python` in Ubuntu 18.04 is still version 2.7](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python).

I suggest you set up a virtualenv with the correct version to simplify this, e.g. via [the `venv` module](https://docs.python.org/library/venv.html) or something like [Pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/).